# Lotus Domino for a complete newbie

Tags: ibm-domino

I need to set up a local domino server (on a local network), and I am completely lost in the process. I don't have any prior experience in those kind of task.

I have installed Domino 8.5 and a 8.0 client, I can receive and send mail but now I need to set up some IMAP and POP3 account.

From what I know, there is supposed to be a Domino Administrator Client. Where can I find this ? Is there another way to configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately all the admin client does is provide a server console and a different view on stuff you can still get to through the main Notes client as most of the server's behaviour is driven from the Directory (names.nsf).

Overall, the online [help](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp) at IBM should be able to give you what you need.

Are you wanting a) the server to provide POP3 / IMAP or b) to access some external accounts from the client?

For the server, follow these links from the help for:  [POP3](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc/DOC/H_DOMINO_POP3_SERVER_OVER.html) and [IMAP](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc/DOC/H_THE_IMAP_SERVICE_OVER.html).
For the client, follow these links from the help for: [POP3](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.notes.help.doc/DOC/H_ACCESSING_INTERNET_INCOMING_POP_MAIL_STEPS.html) and [IMAP](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.notes.help.doc/DOC/H_USING_IMAP_1874_OVER.html).

Comment: In fact what I really is to be able to send mail to the Lotus user. Example : I have a user with name "Administrator" and I want to send him a mail from a .NET application. I can send mail from Notes Client to one another but from the outside is where I'm lost. Completely lost.

Answer (score 0):

When you install the client there is the option to install the administration client.  Install this on your admin machine.
From here you then have to add your server to the admin console then you can select it and see all your mail boxes, connection documents clusters etc.

Comment: provided that you have the "all clients" install package